# How to send on behalf of colleagues account through DocUSign API?

Tags: docusignapi

I, Ryan, have permission profile within "Users" as DS Admin. My colleague John Doe has shared his access with me.

I am using the eSignature REST API to have embedded signing within my website.

My colleague John Doe is the account manager for a number of clients. My other colleague Jane Doe is also the account manager for a number of other clients.

When a client comes onto the website and clicks the "renew now" button they will be direct to the DocUSign website where they will sign their contract before being redirected back to the original website.

Through my website I want to be able to send envelopes as though I am John or Jane Doe when as user clicks the "renew now" button. Currently as it stands, they are being sent as me; Ryan.

I have looked at the [SOBO DocUSign docs](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-soap-api/esign101/auth/send-on-behalf-of/) but I don't think this is the right spot to look?

It might be worth noting that the Template sits in my account.

**I have tried the below:**

POST `https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2.1/accounts/{{DOCUSIGN_API_ACCOUNT_ID}}/envelopes`

**Headers**

```
Authorization:Bearer {{accessToken}}
Content-Type:application/json
X-DocuSign-Act-As-User: {{COLLEAGUE_USER_ID}}
```

**JSON body**

```json
{
  "templateId": "d757ea21-a03a-4401-b24f-49821cc3a8d4",
  "templateRoles": [
    {
      "email": "fury@gmail.com",
      "name": "Tyson Fury",
      "roleName": "signer",
      "clientUserId": "3a25f3de-3bba-4c4b-a7a5-2f3ec696eabc",
      "tabs": {
        "signHereTabs": [
          {
            "anchorString": "/XSIGNHEREX/",
            "anchorUnits": "pixels",
            "anchorXOffset": "20",
            "anchorYOffset": "10",
            "tabLabel": "signHere"
          }
        ],
        "textTabs": [
          {
            "anchorString": "/XLEGALRENEWALPRICEX/",
            "anchorUnits": "pixels",
            "anchorXOffset": "20",
            "anchorYOffset": "10",
            "tabLabel": "renewalPrice",
            "value": "£100.99"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  "status": "sent"
}
```

I do get a 201 Created but it still seems that the envelope is coming from my account.

Can someone please explain how I can send on behalf of Jane and John Doe. I do have shared access with them?

Answer (score 0):

So, one way to do this is using impersonation with JWT tokens.
When you retrieve an access token using [JWT](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/jwt/) (unlike with Auth Code Grant) you have to specify the **userId** of the user to be impersonated. You can impersonate Jane Doe or Joe Doe or whoever you want if you know their **userId**. The **userId** can be found by making an [API call](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/users/users/get/) or can be hardcoded if it's a fixed person(s).
This user does have to grant a one-time [consent](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/consent/) for the application to make API calls on their behalf. Once this is done, the app is free to impersonate them and make API calls if JWT is used to obtain access tokens.